# Is there any way to save different Startup Files?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, video-sequence-editor

So, I like to change, create and edit the Screen Layouts according to what I am going to do in Blender. But recently I had some problems because I have to much Layouts and it is hard to change between Motion Tracking and 3D View (for example). 
Is there some way to save different startup files and when I want to do some VFX I open a type of Blender with only some screen layouts that I set and when I want to just model something I open a different startup file with just screen layouts for modelling?

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 8):

Not currently natively supported, but it is [planned for future 2.8 versions](https://code.blender.org/2016/12/the-blender-101-project-and-you/).

However nothing stops you from having several template files saved somewhere safe in your computer, and opening them as startup templates.

Create a "Startup Files Library" somewhere in your hard drive, and save all your desired startup files there.

You can add the folder as favorite to Blender's built in file manager, and readily open any file from there whenever you require a specific task.

If you open them frequently they may even get listed in the splash screen at startup for easier access.

One other neat trick you may use is to manually lock your `recent-files.txt`as read only, and manually edit it to include only your desired startup files, if you don't mind loosing the convenience of having other recently opened projects readily accessible that is.

It is just a simple plain-text file with one file path per line, so you can edit it externally with any notepad like or programmer's plain-text editor editor.

If you know how to code you can also use the Python API or create an addon for your convenience.

You may also create several desktop shortcuts (or Start Menu or saved them anywhere else you like) each with a different command line parameter, specifying a passed file for Blender to open, effectively starting it as a template. All you have to do then is *Save-As* to the desired location.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can write a shell script written depending on your OS to replace the startup file from one of two different startup blend files. An easier solution to avoid playing with shell scripting would be:

1. Download the .zip version of blender twice
2. Rename the folder of one of them to be "Blender VFX" and the other one "Blender Modelling"
3. Open the .blender in each folder then edit it to make it look like how you want it to be
4. Set the startup of each one to what you want it to look like by going to file-->save as startup file
5. Add a shortcut on Your desktop or something to both blender versions and open the one you want.

Comment: Another thing to add is you could make your own shortcut icons, could look nice in a folder of different blender versions. Only problem is if you had a lot of blender duplicates it would take up a fair bit of storage. (PS on step one you don't really need to download blender twice, just once then duplicate it.

Comment: terrible solution!