# How to enable an addon for all but one file?

Tags: add-on, customization, saving

How do I enable an addon for all but one file in Blender 2.7b?

A more tangible way to express my query would be that if I have 4 Blender (.blend) files, A, B, C, and D, then how do I enable an addon for A, B, and C only but then not for D?

Basically, how do I make the User-Preferences for one file different from the one in others without re-modifying them (the User-Preferences) again every single time on startup? (And no, I do not mean to "save different startup files". Explaining one last time: You know how there is a button which saves the user's prefs for all Blender files? Well, how do I save them for all *but one* file?)

Thanks a lot, and hope you have an amazing day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to save different Startup Files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71207/is-there-any-way-to-save-different-startup-files)

Comment: What addon are you asking about?

Comment: @TheCatalyst Any addon, it doesn't matter which one.

Comment: It is what different startup files are meant for. You technically could open *that one* file first, then open new Blender session, save new user prefs wit addon enabled and then open other files but that would be for one session only.

Comment: Yeah, I want for all sessions that I use _in a particular file._